# Android Firebase Google SIgnon bad request

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

Android Firebase Google signin through authorization error when google return token id. i have both cleint id as well as web sdk key saved on firebase. Even json file.

```
 AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(OnBoarding.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        // ...
                    }
                });
```

Got this error

```
com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occured. [ Bad Request ]
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzacq.zzbN(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzacn$zzg.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzacy.zzbO(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzacy$zza.onFailure(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzact$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
```

Though google signIn went well there is something missing with firebase which m not able to figure out need help

Logs

```
"error": {
    "errors": [{
        "domain": "usageLimits",
        "reason": "keyExpired",
        "message": "Bad Request"
    }],
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Bad Request"
}

                                                   }
```

Comment: I am having the same problem...although my stack trace shows line 446 in Binder.java as the root.   Anyway...how did you get the json error log?

Answer (score 7):

In the firebase console (Overview) Under Your mobile apps click the overflow button (three vertical dots) and goto Manage.

Once there goto your app and download the google-services.json

Add that to the root directory of your app and also to the /app folder.

This worked for me to fix this exact error. I assume I changed something at some point and needed a new one.

Hopefully this helps. Goodluck

Comment: Try to re-sync your gradle, at a some point I used to delete my app from Firebase (not the project). In the overview of firebase you can find all your apps, then just reconfigure your settings.

Answer (score 0):

Some reason to get [[ Bad Request ]](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/).

**Error Conditions:**

The Firebase REST API will return error codes under these circumstances.

1) **404 Not Found**   :  *A request made over HTTP instead of HTTPS*

2) **400 Bad Request**  :  *Unable to parse PUT or POST data*

3) **400 Bad Request** :  *Missing PUT or POST data*

4) **400 Bad Request** : *Attempting to PUT or POST data which is too large*

5) **417 Expectation Failed** : *A REST API call that doesn't specify a Firebase name*

6) **400 Bad Request** : *A REST API call that contains invalid child names as part of the path*

7) **403 Forbidden**  : *A request that violates your Security and Firebase Rules*

Check which type of parameter or other things are missing in request as per above option.

I hope its helps you.

Comment: hey i have added error logs have a look if you can figure out

Comment: Good. I will check

Comment: Why downvote! Answer should point the reasons why error occurred.